# SharePoint 2007: No search results for sites within one content db

Tags: 2007, search-results, crawling

I have a situation where search is not returning any results for site within a specific content DB.   Search is working perfectly for other sites in my environment.

I looked at below post and the databaseRepair command does not report any orphan objects in the content DB.

[Crawling does not happing on a content database from set of DBs of my Web Application (MOSS)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/ffadb6c3-3a28-4add-837a-387273354387)

I also looked at the permission and everything looks the same as compared to other content DB.

Any idea what could be potential issue with this content DB.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does this content database represent a whole web application or a site collection within a larger web application?  If the latter, are other sites in that web application being indexed?

Comment: Thanks Dave,  This content DB had about 40 sites and all of them were showing the same behavior,  we noticed that there were some orphan site map entry in this content DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that all the site collection within this Content DB were showing the same behavior,  That hinted me that Crawler is not able to complete crawling for this content database.

We found that this content DB had one orphan entry in the site map,  we re-attached the DB and started the crawling again,  this resolved the issue.

Thanks for all your help.